# Updating info in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning php, and right now I'm stuck. I have code that has to update info in table called title with fields id and zagolovok, but it doesnt update, and shows white screen with no errors.

```
$db = mysql_connect('server', 'login', 'passr' );
mysql_select_db(u20221, $db);  
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE title SET zagolovok = '$_REQUEST[title]' WHERE id = 5");  
mysql_close($db);
```

Ps server/login/pass changed due to privacy

Comment: what is the error check mysql_error();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't bother learning the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Read the FAQ section here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info to learn how to turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$db = mysql_connect('server', 'login', 'passr' );
if( !$db) die("no connection");
mysql_select_db(u20221, $db);  
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE title SET zagolovok = '".$_REQUEST['title']."' WHERE id = 5");  
mysql_close($db);
```

Is title your table name or your column ???
The Syntax is
 `UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE ...`

Comment: title its name of my table, zagolovok is name of column

Answer (score 1):

```
$_REQUEST[title]   $_REQUEST is an array use $_REQUEST['title'] 
 $query = mysql_query('UPDATE title SET zagolovok = "\'$_REQUEST['title']\'" WHERE id = 5');
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on error reporting and it'll tell you that you need to include quotes around your database name.

To do this, at the top of your index (or executed file) add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And to ensure it's visible in your browser:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Also worth noting that your code is vulnerable to `SQL Injection`, to fix this (and your other undefined constant):

```
$safeTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']);
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE title SET zagolovok = '$safeTitle' WHERE id = 5");
```

Alternatively you could switch to [`PDO`](http://php.net/PDO) and use prepared statements which is highly recommended.

Comment: This worked fine for me and i think rest would be too, but by my own inattention i used 'title' instead of 'Title', which was correct row name in my db